# Android App get crashed when webview open

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I am trying to transfer variable (url_1) value from main activity to webview. But when I click button app get crashed. I also use putExtra but it doesn't work. Please have a look on below code.

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
    String [] result;
    Context context;
    int [] imageId;
    private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;
    public CustomAdapter(MainActivity mainActivity, String[] prgmNameList, int[] prgmImages) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        result=prgmNameList;
        context=mainActivity;
        imageId=prgmImages;
        inflater = ( LayoutInflater )context.
                getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return result.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    public class Holder
    {
        TextView tv;
        ImageView img;
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Holder holder=new Holder();
        View rowView;
        rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.new_custom_list, null);
        holder.tv=(TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        holder.img=(ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        holder.tv.setText(result[position]);
        holder.img.setImageResource(imageId[position]);
        rowView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent myIntent = null;
                if (position == 0) {
                    CustomAdapter.this.context.startActivity(new Intent(CustomAdapter.this.context, BalanceActivity.class));
                }
                if (position == 1) {
                    String url_1 = "http://www.facebook.com";
                    myIntent.putExtra("url", url_1);
                    CustomAdapter.this.context.startActivity(new Intent(CustomAdapter.this.context, WebShow1.class));

                }
            }
        });
        return rowView;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have downvoted [for urgent begging](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326569/under-what-circumstances-may-i-add-urgent-or-other-similar-phrases-to-my-quest). Please refrain from addressing volunteers in this way in your future questions, thanks!

Comment: can´t find a urgent begging in that question...is it deleted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `myIntent` is null. You are creating it with:

```
Intent myIntent = null;
```

and without initializing you want to put some data inside:

```
myIntent.putExtra("url", url_1);
```

I don´t know what you want to do with `myIntent`but it must be initialized, in an Activity for example with

```
myIntent = getIntent();
```

in your adapter, you can reference it from context like:

```
Intent myIntent = ((Activity) context).getIntent();
```

and be sure intent is not null before doing something with it:

```
if(myIntent!=null){
//do your stuff
}
```

or, if you for example want to start a new Activity (in your case):

```
 Intent myIntent = null;
                if (position == 0) {
                    myIntent = new Intent(CustomAdapter.this.context, BalanceActivity.class);
                    CustomAdapter.this.context.startActivity(myIntent);
                }
                if (position == 1) {

                    myIntent = new Intent(CustomAdapter.this.context, WebShow1.class);
                    String url_1 = "http://www.facebook.com";
                    myIntent.putExtra("url", url_1);
                    CustomAdapter.this.context.startActivity(myIntent);

                }
```

Comment: Hello @Opiatefuchs Thanks for your quick reply... I have add whole activity code. Please let me know what things I need to edit. I am a beginner programmer, still in learning basic of coding.

Answer (score 1):

You are  doing it completely wrong my intent variable will always be null.And you are starting activity with new Intent object and then adding vaibales to different intent object.You need to use same Intent object and first put variables in it and then start intent.

like this

```
Intent myIntent  = new Intent(this,WebShow1.class);
myIntent.putExtra("url", url_1);
startActivity(myIntent);
```

and in WebView Class

```
String url = getIntent().getExtras().getString("url");
```